# Encoding problem in exception text output in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, encoding

This is my first question here. I have not found a solution to my specific problem here. The error text in Russian is displayed incorrectly in the SpringBoot application.
What have I tried:

- Add

  ```
  <configuration>
      <executable>true</executable>
      <jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</jvmArguments>
  </configuration>
  ```

in pom.xml

- Add

  ```
  -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  ```

in Help > Edit Custom VM Options.

- Change project encoding and file encoding to UTF-8 in Settings.

[In the screenshot, you can see how the same text is displayed in Postman and in the IDEA console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ0iT.png)

Comment: My terminal can't read text from images (_please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]_) however you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Искомый'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252','replace')` returns `'Ð˜Ñ�ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ñ‹Ð¹'`

Comment: What run configuration is used to start the application? Is it Gradle task, or Spring boot run config? If second one, please show your run configuration screenshot

Comment: Seems very similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219115/gradle-task-output-The-Chinese-characters-garbled-and-Chinese-input-window-on-bottom-right-corner

Comment: Check also font settings and add additional jnu.encoding VM option: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4413449581458/comments/4413547677330

Comment: Did you configure the database to use Unicode data?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I'm not really good at this yet, but I use the Maven build system, and I start the application by simply pressing the run button. If you describe in more detail what I need to show you, I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running your IntelliJ on Windows. Apparently UTF-8 has a bug there for cyrillic. Try to set the terminal to windows-1251: Bottom right in your screenshot is currently selected "UTF-8" click on that and under "more" you should be able to select windows-1251.

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206606945-Displaying-cyrillic-symbols-in-terminal

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but, unfortunately, it didn't help me - after switching to windows-1251, the characters really changed, but still have nothing to do with Cyrillic, besides, the error text stopped being displayed correctly in Postman. Can you give any more advice?